# Showing Alert on samsung smart TV

Tags: javascript, html, tizen, samsung-smart-tv

I am working on a tizen application on Samsung smart TV, when I create an alert with `window.alert()` it works on emulator but on TV.

Here's the code:

```
mac = webapis.network.getMac();
console.log(mac);
window.alert(mac);
```

Is there a solution?

Comment: You'll need to share some more info on what you've tried, your code, any errors given, etc.

Comment: Please don't provide code in comments, you can [edit] your question to add relevant details like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you using Tizen Network API add internet access privilege for your Tizen application in the config.xml file.Internet Privilege allows the application to access the Internet.

```
<tizen:privilege name="tizen.org/privilege/internet"/>
<tizen:privilege name="http://developer.samsung.com/privilege/network.public"/>
```

Also defining external access Policy may be required to access network. According to the W3C Access Requests Policy (WARP), you cannot access external network resources by default. If you require access to an external network resource, you must request network resource permissions for the Web application using the Policy in the config.xml file.

```
<access origin="*" subdomains="true"/>
```

Now your application should be able to access MAC address from the real devices as like as emulators and you should be able to alert MAC adress from TV devices.

Answer (score 0):

use directly: `alert(mac);`
instead of :`window.alert(mac);`

I think because you have not privilege to call the function getMac()
for this reason mac=null, and alert(mac) dont show any thing.

Thanks.

Comment: "instead of windows.alert(mac);" ... there is no such code shown in the question.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: You seem to be online and trying to improve your post. Good. You seem however to have missed the point of my two previous comments. For one, either you have a typo in your answer (and additional "s") or you should explain that you assume a typo in the code shown in the question (a missing "s"). For another, you better should explain how your proposed solution will achieve on emulator and on the TV what OP is trying.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).